# Changing working directory in a client/server environment in python

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, subprocess, client-server

Im trying to figure out the easiest way to change my working directory on my client script using the "cd" command from my server script, yet whenever I run the dir command the current working directory does not change. here is my code:

Server Code:

```
import subprocess
import socket

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(("0.0.0.0", 443))
server_socket.listen(1)
connected_socket = server_socket.accept()[0]

while True:
    encoded_data = connected_socket.recv(1024)
    data = encoded_data.decode()

    if data != "None":
        print(data)
        nextcmd = input("Shell: ")
        connected_socket.send(nextcmd.encode())
    else:
        nextcmd = input("Shell: ")
        connected_socket.send(nextcmd.encode())
```

Client Code:

```
import subprocess
import socket

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

passwd = "secret"

host = "127.0.0.1" #server
port = 443 #port for listener


def Shell():
    while True:
        encoded_data = client_socket.recv(1024)
        data = encoded_data.decode()

        if data == "kill":
            client_socket.close()
            break
        elif data[:2] == "cd":
            client_socket.send("OK".encode())
            continue

        proc = subprocess.Popen(data, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
        output = proc.communicate()[0] + proc.communicate()[1]
        client_socket.send(output)


def Login():
    global client_socket
    client_socket.send("Login Required".encode())
    pwd = client_socket.recv(1024)

    if pwd.decode() != passwd:
        Login()
    else:
        client_socket.send("connected".encode())
        Shell()


client_socket.connect((host, port))
Login()
```

Comment: In case you were wondering, that's not secure at all.

Comment: Not using encryption or the storing the password locally thing? In aware im just testing it for now. Plenty of changes coming

Comment: Both of those, plus your attempts to stop `kill` commands. If you run this, use a whitelist-only `sudoers` file and completely lock off everything from the user running the shell, juuuuust in case. But if they get that far, you've lost.

Comment: Im fairly new to python, and im using the kill command to close the shell, is this bad practice? How would you go about it?

Comment: I'd use `exit` or `logout`, because `kill` is the program that kills other processes. I thought that was a feeble attempt to block the use of the `kill` command by silently closing the connection.

Comment: No it was strictly for me to close the connection so i can make changes and run it again, same as me keeping the password local for now, I plan on using a user pass combo, and defining a function to handle both encryption and encoding. Just tryna get the basic functionality working first. Been having problems trying to change the directory on the client pc though

Comment: It's because you're changing the directory of the shell.

Comment: Could you explain how to make all the commands run in one shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a new shell each time, try creating a single shell process and putting all of the input into that. That way, after the shell has changed its own directory it won't immediately close.

I'm not very familiar with the `subprocess` module, but I think you can do this by opening a single shell process and communicating with it via [`process.communicate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate), setting the `timeout` parameter and using a loop so that you can send a `^C` to stop a hung program.

Comment: Wow... I didnt realize I was creating multiple shells lol, how can I make it all one shell?

Comment: @calinative707 I've updated the answer; does this help? Sorry for the delay.

Comment: Yss i think i can do that, appreciate the help

Comment: @calinative707 If that's not working out, you can reimplement the shell-like stuff yourself: https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#module-shlex

Comment: Im having trouble getting the multiple commands to work in one shell, mostly because i dont have a solid understanding of how to do it

Comment: @calinative707 That may have something to do with the `subprocess` module not being designed to support it. How about you make a chatroom so we can discuss this further? [chat]'s the site. I've got to go now, but I'll see if I can talk to you about it in several hours. Btw, you could use SSH.